# Scala equivalent of Java's Number

Tags: scala

I am trying to construct a type hierarchy for numerical domain types. e.g. a `Year` is an `Int` (which is a `Number`), a `Percentage` is a `Double`, which is a `Number`, etc. I need the hierarchy so that I can call `toInt` or `toDouble` on the values.

However, the Scala type hierarchy for the primitive numeric types has no common ancestor except `AnyVal`. This does not contain the `to{Int, Double}` functions that I need.

The closest type I could find is `Numeric[T]`, which seems to exist primarily for some compiler trickery.

In Java, all the numbers derived from `Number` (including the arbitrary precision ones). **How does one define an interface that caters for numerical types of object in Scala?**

I'm currently hacking it with duck typing:

```
Any {
  def toInt: Int
  def toDouble: Double
}
```

which is not only long-winded, but incurs runtime reflection costs. Is there anything better?

Comment: What is the use case for calling `toDouble` on a `Year`?

Comment: @BenJames there is not... this is simply illustrative.

Comment: Well, `Numeric` typeclass is really the way to go, but Scala still uses Java's `Number` class, so you can use it too.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`Numeric[T]` is exactly what you are looking for. Scala's way to go here is type classes (i.e. a thing like `Numeric`).

Instead of

```
def foo(x: java.lang.Number) = x.doubleValue
```

write one of

```
def foo[T](x: T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = n.toDouble(x)
def foo[T : Numeric](x: T) = implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(x)
```

where the second is (almost) nothing but syntactic sugar.

### Numeric.Ops

Writing calls to the instance of `Numeric` every time you need an operation can become clumsy when the expression is more complex. To mitigate this, `Numeric` provides the implicit conversion `mkNumericOps` which augment `T` with the common ways of writing mathematical operations (i.e. `1 + 2` rather than `n.plus(1,2)`).

In order to use those, just import the members of the implicit `Numeric`:

```
def foo[T](x: T)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = {
  import n._
  x.toDouble
}
```

Note that due to restrictions on `import` the abbreviated syntax for the implicit is hardly desirable here.

### Type Classes

What happens here? If an argument list is marked as `implicit`, the compiler will automatically put a value of the required type there iff exactly one value of that type that is marked as `implicit` exists in scope. If you write

```
foo(1.0)
```

The compiler will automatically change this to

```
foo(1.0)(Numeric.DoubleIsFractional)
```

providing the method `foo` with operations on `Double`.

The *huge* advantage of this is that you can make types `Numeric` without them knowing. Suppose you have a library that gives you a type `MyBigInt`. Now suppose that in the Java world - unfortunately - the developers did not make it extend `Number`. There is nothing you can do.

In Scala, you can just write

```
implicit object MyBigIntIsNumeric extends Numeric[MyBigInt] {
   def compare(x: MyBigInt, y: MyBigInt) = ...
   // ...
}
```

and all your code using `Numeric` will now work with `MyBigInt` but **you did not have to change the library**. So `Numeric` could even be private to your project and this pattern would still work.

Comment: @LomigMégard has suggested an edit that explains the implicit magic better. I will edit the post.

Answer (score -1):

the answer from @gzm0 is a static solution, which the type must be checked in compiling time, I give a dynamic solution which cast the type in runtime,

`def toDoubleDynamic(x: Any) = x match {
     case s: String => s.toDouble
     case jn: java.lang.Number => jn.doubleValue()
     case _ => throw new ClassCastException("cannot cast to double")
}`

It use case match to choose the correct type in runtime.

Comment: It depends situation. In my case, I use scala in spark framework. DataFrame (in spark) object has the field of different numeric type, I can't get it at compile time, but most spark api require double field, if not, it would throw exceptions, so the dynamic solution works in my application.

Comment: my comment was deleted, not by me. I'll repeat it. This answer is the complete opposite of idiomatic Scala. If you find yourself wanting to do it this way, you're using the wrong language or should spend some time to understand the value of compile time typing.

Comment: @fommit  But, still it happens.  I'm dynamically generating a table in HTML and the values can be absolutely anything and I need to select a CSS class based on whether it's numeric.  It's not a language issue.  You're right that it shouldn't be preferred but, sometimes, it's the only way.  We are grateful for reflection and runtime typing.