# How work with Numeric scala type?

Tags: java, scala, numbers, numeric

In Java I can work with [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) like that

```
public void myFunction(Number number) {
    double innerVar = 1.0; //initial value
    if (number != null) {
        innerVar += number.doubleValue();
    }
    //do other logic
}
```

If I need to work with `Integer` I can replace `doubleValue` code with `intValue`.

But scala.math.Numeric do no have such methods only like `toDouble(x:T)` I do not know what is `x:T` parameter here. Also if you see `scala.Double` or
`scala.Short` they have method `toDouble` but these methods are not inherits from one trait.

I can use pattern matching, but there is a lot of code duplication with `toDouble`:

```
val myNum:AnyVal = ...
var innerDouble = 1.0
myNum match {
    case Double => innerDouble + myNum
    case Short => innerDouble.toDouble + myNum
    case Int => innerDouble.toDouble + myNum
}
```

or another variant

```
val myNum:AnyVal = ...
var innerDouble = 1.0
myNum match {
    case Double | Short | Int | Long => innerDouble.toDouble + myNum
    case _ =>
}
```

So how is there a better way to work with work with Numeric types with Scala?

**P.S.**

I read about view bounds in scala like `<% double`, but do not know how they can be used in pattern matching.

**UPDATED**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999409/scala-equivalent-of-javas-number) is similar question, but it about classes and parameters in it, I need solution for using in pattern matching.

Comment: Please check this other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999409/scala-equivalent-of-javas-number

Comment: Checked, but not understand how to use it in pattern matching. :(

Comment: @Cherry The point of using `Numeric` is that you don't need to use pattern matching to add `myNum` to `innerDouble`.

Comment: Yep, but in my case I need to be sure that only "Number" support `toDouble` (e.g. all scala typse which are view of double), but with implicit's (as I understand) anybody can write implicit conversion with double and code will work with that type, but I do not need such behavior here. E.g. the goal to use double views not every class with implicit conversion.

Comment: @Cherry In both the answer linked by @anquegi and the example I posted in mine, what is implicit is not the conversion (from `AnyVal` to `Double`) but an object wich provides the conversion. Given that the implicit value is only resolved if this object is of the type `Numeric[T]` and that there are only such implicit objects  for  `T`s which support `toDouble` you are actually constraining your attribute's type.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround, a dirty alternative to `Numeric` type class, is to get the string representation of `myNum` and parse it using `String.toDouble`:

```
val myNum:AnyVal = ...
var innerDouble = 1.0

val res = myNum.toString.toDouble + innerDouble
```

If `myNum` does not contain a parseable as double value, the parsing step will throw a `NumberFormatException`

It isn't elegant but the code is short.

To sum up, you can use `Numeric`:

```
def myFunction[T : Numeric](number: T) = {
    var innerVar = 1.0;
    innerVar = implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(number) + innerVar;
    innerVar
}
```

Or take advantage of string parsing:

```
def myFunction(number: AnyVal) = {
    var innerVar = 1.0;
    innerVar = number.toString.toDouble + innerVar;
    innerVar
}
```

Being the second option formally uglier, it allows actual arguments for `number` such as `"3.3"`.