# Trying to create a generic function to sum elements of a Tree

Tags: scala, generics

I'm using the tree defined here...

https://gist.github.com/schmmd/1271891

where...

```
class Tree[+T]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing] 
case class Node[T](val elem: T, val left: Tree[T], val right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
```

I added this trait...

```
trait sum[T] {
  def +(value: T): T
}
```

and I defined this tree...

```
val a = Node(1, Node(1, Empty, Node(5, Empty, Empty)), Node(2, Node(3, Empty, Empty), Empty))
```

Then I wrote this function to sum up the elements...

```
def sumTree[T <: sum[T]](t: Tree[T]): T = t match {
    case Empty => 0
    case Node(e, left, right) => e + sumTree(left) + sumTree(right)
}
```

**Questions**

1)  Why is it that I have to define a trait (assuming I've defined this properly) to use "+"?  Without it, the compiler treats it as trying to concatenate a string.

2)  I'm not sure how to handle "empty".  I want to treat "Empty" as 0 when pattern matching but I can't because of generic handling.  Is it that I can't make this work with generics?  I would have to specify the type it accepts / returns beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your element type `T` is generic, you need to provide a helper structure to deal with addition. Scala wouldn't know how to add two elements of type `T` without further information. That's why you define a trait `sum`. As you correctly suspect, you also need a way to know what the zero element is. So you would rather use something like this:

```
trait Sum[T] {
  def zero: T
  def plus(x: T, y: T): T
}
```

Note that we define `plus` with *two* operands. Then instead of requiring that `T <: Sum[T]` be a sub-type of `Sum`, you provide an implicit value (called type-class). This makes it easier to use your tree with arbitrary types even if an element doesn't implement `Sum`.

There are existing type-classes that could fulfil this function which is basically a "monoid". The Scala standard class library has [`Numeric`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.math.Numeric) which you could use. It is a bit more than just a monoid, defining several arithmetic operations, including `zero` and `plus`.

Then your aggregate function becomes:

```
def sumTree[T](t: Tree[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = t match {
  case Empty => num.zero
  case Node(e, left, right) => 
    num.plus(e, num.plus(sumTree(left), sumTree(right)))
}
```

You can also import some syntactic helper:

```
def sumTree[T](t: Tree[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]): T = t match {
  case Empty => num.zero
  case Node(e, left, right) => 
    import num.mkNumericOps
    e + sumTree(left) + sumTree(right)
}
```

---

See also:

- [Scala equivalent of Java's Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999409/scala-equivalent-of-javas-number)
- http://like-a-boss.net/2012/07/30/ordering-and-ordered-in-scala.html

Comment: Thanks!  What if I wanted to stick with using the trait?  How would I use zero / plus in that case?  I get an error that zero / plus cannot be resolved

Comment: Well you can add `zero` to your original trait, like `trait sum[T] { def zero: T; def +(value: T): T }`, but it doesn't make that much sense because it is unrelated to the current represented value... Also then your `sumTree` method would require a value of type `T` to be able to access `zero`. Or you write `def sumTree[T <: sum[T]](t: Tree[T], zero: T): T`. Therefore I would recommend you stick to a type-class such as `Numeric`.

Comment: ok thank you.  It seems a bit messy to stick with the trait so I'll work with Numeric