# Clarification of Scala function

Tags: scala

I am trying to execute this function

```
def sumofdouble[T <:Number] (as:T*): Double = as.foldLeft(0d)(_ + _.doubleValue)
```

If I try using this function like this,

```
sumofdouble(1,2)
```

I am getting this error

```
<console>:13: error: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method sumofdouble's type parameter bounds [T <: Number]
sumofdouble(1,2)
```

Isn't Integer a subtype of Number? Please explain if I am missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using `java.lang.Number`. Unfortunatelly, numeric types in scala do not inherit from this class (for reference look at `Int` definition - like other scala's numerics it inherits directly from `AnyVal` - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int.html) - it is simply not in their hierarchy. What you want to use is the implicit `Numeric` type class to convert your numbers.

`def foo[T](as: T*)(implicit n: Numeric[T]) = as.foldLeft(0d)(_ + n.toDouble(_))`

See this question for further information - [Scala equivalent of Java's Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999409/scala-equivalent-of-javas-number).