# Why can't I convert this type into a generic one?

Tags: scala, generics, type-conversion, generic-programming, generic-collections

```
def linearInterpolation(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Seq[T] = {

  weights.zip(points).map(
    weight_point => weight_point._2.map(coordinate => weight_point._1 * coordinate)
  ).reduce((point_a : Seq[Double], point_b : Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => (coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2).asInstanceOf[T]))

}
```

In this code, I'm trying to convert the type of the return, a `Seq[Double]`, to a `Seq[T]`. At the execution of the call, `T` could be e.g. `Double` or `Int`.

This conversion should be realized thanks to `.asInstanceOf[T]`.

## Errors

The code compiles.

But if I execute it, I get the following errors :

> Error:(25, 61) type mismatch;
>    found   : (Seq[Double], Seq[Double]) => Seq[T]
>    required: (Seq[Any], Seq[Any]) => Seq[Any]
>       ).reduce((point_a : Seq[Double], point_b : Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => (coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2).asInstanceOf[T]))
>
> Error:(25, 13) type mismatch;
>    found   : Seq[Any]
>    required: Seq[T]
>       ).reduce((point_a : Seq[Double], point_b : Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => (coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2).asInstanceOf[T]))

## Question

Why does the execution fail ? How to achieve this conversion from a `Seq[Double]` to a `Seq[T]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, no, this code doesn't compile: those are compilation errors, not runtime exceptions. You can see because it starts with `Error:`, points to an exact position in source code (exceptions only have a line number), and there's no stack trace.

Now, if it did compile, it wouldn't work, but that's a separate issue.

So why doesn't it compile? The type of `weights.zip(points).map(...)` is `Seq[Seq[Double]]`, so the signature of `reduce` becomes `reduce[A1 >: Seq[Double]](op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1`. Note that the return and argument types of `reduce`'s argument must match, and in your case they don't (you have `(Seq[Double], Seq[Double]) => Seq[T]`). By itself that would be enough not to compile.

The expected type of the entire `weights.zip(points).map(...).reduce(...)` is `Seq[T]`, so the compiler needs to pick `A1` which is:

1. a supertype of `Seq[Double]` to satisfy the constraint
2. a subtype of `Seq[T]` to make return types match

Such a type doesn't exist (without additional constraints on `T`), but if it did it would be `Seq[SomeType]`, and that's as far as the compiler should get. Why it ends up showing `Any`, I really don't see.

> How to achieve this conversion from a Seq[Double] to a Seq[T] ?

It makes more sense if you have `weights: Seq[T], points: Seq[Seq[T]]`. In that case, use `Numeric`. There's quite a few answers on Stack Overflow and outside explaining how, e.g. [Scala equivalent of Java's Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999409/scala-equivalent-of-javas-number).

For `weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]`, I would just add a function `Double => T` as an extra argument:

```
def linearInterpolation(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]])(fromDouble: Double => T) : Seq[T] = {

  weights.zip(points).map(
    weight_point => weight_point._2.map(coordinate => weight_point._1 * coordinate)
  ).reduce((point_a : Seq[Double], point_b : Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2)).map(fromDouble)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your very complete answer! However, your last code implies to define `fromDouble` (i.e. : to define some converters). Do you think it would be possible, instead, to declare `weights : Seq[Numeric]`, `points : Seq[Numeric]` and the return of my function `Numeric` ? `Numeric` or something else. And in my call, I would be able to use `Double` for the both first, and `Int` for the latter : the conversion would be automatic. Thus, the return of my function would be OK and `reduce` would have arguments' type = return's type.

Comment: "And in my call, I would be able to use Double for the both first, and Int for the latter : the conversion would be automatic" Numeric by itself isn't enough, you'd need to add extra implicit conversions, but your algorithm really doesn't fit well there. It naturally gives the same type of output as inputs. At least if `*` and `+` preserve types like they do in Scala.

Comment: You _can_ do this with the approach in @Gabor Kolok's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I augment answer from Alexey.
I would declare the fromDouble as implicit and create converter functions as implicit values and you could use your function as you designed.
Eg.:

```
object DoubleConverters {
  implicit val doubleToDouble: Double => Double = identity
  implicit val doubleToInt: Double => Int = _.round.toInt
}

def linearInterpolation[T](weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]])(implicit converter: Double => T) : Seq[T] =
  weights.zip(points)
     .map(weight_point => weight_point._2.map(coordinate => weight_point._1 * coordinate))
     .reduce((point_a: Seq[Double], point_b: Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => (coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2)))
     .map(converter)

// sample call
val result = linearInterpolation[Double]( weights = Seq(1.1, 1.3), Seq(Seq(1.1, 1.2), Seq(1.3, 1.4)))
```

// sample call
val result = linearInterpolation[Double]( weights = Seq(1.1, 1.3), Seq(Seq(1.1, 1.2), Seq(1.3, 1.4)))

Comment: But note that `implicit Double => Int` is very easy to use accidentally and lose precision when you don't want to. Also implicit `T => T` (including `Double => Double`) is already available in `Predef`.

Comment: Yes, doubleToDouble is unneeded. If accidental usage of implicit Double => Int is concerned, we can create a type class for that. A few more lines of course.

Answer (score 2):

So the same effect with type class:

```
trait DoubleConverter[T] {
    def convert(d: Double): T
}

object DoubleConverter {
    implicit val doubleToInt: DoubleConverter[Int] = new DoubleConverter[Int] {
        override def convert(d: Double): Int = d.round.toInt
    }

    implicit val doubleToDouble: DoubleConverter[Double] = new DoubleConverter[Double] {
        override def convert(d: Double): Double = d
    }
}

def linearInterpolation[T](weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]])(implicit converter: DoubleConverter[T]) : Seq[T] =
    weights.zip(points)
       .map(weight_point => weight_point._2.map(coordinate => weight_point._1 * coordinate))
       .reduce((point_a: Seq[Double], point_b: Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => (coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2)))
       .map(converter.convert)

// sample call
val result = linearInterpolation[Int]( weights = Seq(1.1, 1.3), Seq(Seq(1.1, 1.2), Seq(1.3, 1.4)))
```

See that usage remains the same. And we avoid accidental Double => Int usage.