# Scala equivalent of Java's Number with divide method

Tags: scala

I want to generalise this function

```
def selfSufficiency(a: Seq[Double], b: Seq[Double]): Double = 
  a.sum/b.sum
```

I tried using the ideas provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999409/scala-equivalent-of-javas-number/17999746#17999746) to implement a more general function that work with Doubles, Floats, Ints, etc.:

```
def selfSufficiency[A](a: Seq[A], b: Seq[A])
     (implicit n: Numeric[A]):A = {
 import n._
 a.sum/b.sum
}
```

I however get a remark from eclipse saying that

> value / is not a member of type parameter A.

1- How can I implement this in functional/generalisable way?

2- Does my implementation limits the user to have the same type "A" for both inputs? In other words, can I do this with my code?

```
selfSufficiency(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(2.0,1.3))
```

if I cannot, please explain how to implement this?

Please note that the code here provide a toy example. In my production function, I add, subtract, find the larger number, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) doesn't encode the division function - you need a [`Fractional`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Fractional.html).

Thus your code becomes

```
def selfSufficiency[A](a: Seq[A], b: Seq[A])
     (implicit n: Fractional[A]):A = {
 import n._
 a.sum/b.sum
}
```

And now it works.

**Edit**
I just read this part of your question.

> Does my implementation limits the user to have the same type "A" for both inputs? In other words, can I do this with my code?

Because both `Fractional` and `Numeric` are parametrized in just one `T`, both arguments have to be from the same type - for example take a look to the [`div` *function*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Fractional.html#div(x:T,y:T):T).

However, since numeric values of less precision are subtypes of the ones with higher *(fig 1)*. You can make it work by upcast, but you will need to help the compiler a little more.

```
selfSufficiency[Double](Seq(1,2,3), Seq(2.0,1.3)) // res1: Double = 1.8181818181818183
```

**Note:** Without specifying the type as `Double`, the compiler will yield the following error.

`error: could not find implicit value for parameter n: Fractional[AnyVal]`

**fig 1**

[image: scala-hierarchy]

*Reference:* https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/scalas-hierarchy.html

Comment: can you please answer q2.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [Fractional](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/math/Fractional.html) trait which is a more narrow Numeric (subtype) that supports [`div`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/math/Fractional.html#div(x:T,y:T):T).